# Jquery not to open popups in hover with window.open and mousenter

Tags: jquery, popup, window.open, mouseenter

Hi i've been searching and trying things to achieve this and haven't found anything to make it work.

The thing is I am using gallerific.js so what I wanted is to hover the images without having to click with the links, I achieved that, then I wanted to make links linkable and it works, my only problem is that as I am using mousenter in the same class that I use window.open, site tries to open me popups with the link to open.window.
Here is my code:

```
 <li> 
 <a class="thumb" href="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>           
<script type="text/javascript">      
$("a.thumb").click(function(){
    window.open("index.php?route=product/product&product_id=<? echo $rest;?>")

});
</script>
</li>
```

And here is the mousenter function:

```
   $('a.thumb').mouseenter(function(e)
{ 
    $(this).click();

});
```

What i want to achieve is to have both thing combined without having 'hovered' links
Any help would be really appreciated! thank you!

Solved it, here is the answer:

```
         <?php  foreach ($products as $product) { 
          $enlace= $product['href']; 
          $rest = substr($enlace, -2); 
          ?>

     <li> 
     <a class="thumb" href="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"><p class="thumb2"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></p></a>         
    <script type="text/javascript">      
    $("p.thumb2").click(function(){
        window.open("index.php?route=product/product&product_id=<? echo $rest;?>", "_self")

    });
    </script>
    </li>

         <?} ?>
            </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Makes hover work instead of click on gallery
            $('a.thumb').mouseenter(function(e)
{ 
    $(this).click();

});</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do is not possible, you are trying to bind 2 different events, however if you are going to click the mouse will have to hover it first, you can't avoid that, I suggest reevaluating your strategy, maybe adding  a different link to trigger your pop up or changing classes and triggering different events depending on which class is hovered or clicked.

Comment: yes I tried that the thing is that the list is inside a loop, the moment I add new classes like for instance <a class="thumb"><p class="thumb2"></p></a>  all links turn to be the same

Comment: can you add any logic in your back end to add  different link ? which language you using?

Comment: how do you generate your look for the links?

Comment: from php, they are inside an array I make a substring from it to get product identity:
$enlace= $product['href']; 
 $rest = substr($enlace, -2);

Comment: the moment I add <p> inside <a> links turn to be the last link from the loop, but if I don't add <p> links work okay

Comment: what if you create 2 links ? one thtat can be clickable and the ohter only for hovering

Comment: thats what I tried:
 <a class="thumb" href="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" </a> this is the hover and the other link would be inside <p> and in window.open("") it has another link, the prob is that with this solution links from window.open are always the same

Comment: can you please edit your q uestion to include your php code? I will look at it and take it from there